# How you manually parse a raw request withtout using express.raw()

Tags: javascript, express, realm

i'm implementing Stripe Webhooks and everything works fine but I'm having problems validating the payload when there are special characters(example, áéíóú). The code:

```
  const endpointSecret = "whsec_xxx";      
  // stripe signature
  const sig = headers['Stripe-Signature'][0]        

  const stripe = require('stripe')(
    'sk_test_yyy'
    );
    
  //const buf = new Buffer(body, 'base64');
  // let text = buff.toString('ascii');
    
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body.text(), sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    response.setStatusCode(400);
    throw err;
  }
```

The thing is that i'm using Realm MongoDB HTTP EndPoints that don't support adding a body parser in the function. So What I have is just this:

```
exports = async function({ query, headers, body }, response) {
```

I can read the raw body using body.text() and this works fine in most cases, but not all.

What I Need is to emulate the JSON parsing when I declare the function like this:

```
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
```

This way always works. But I don't know how to manually parse the body in the same way that bodyparse does it.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; it says - *having problems validating the payload when there are special characters* - but the code doesn't appear to show what kind of problems you're having. It then states - *I can read the raw body using body.text() and this works fine in most cases, but not all.* - so is the question about the cases where it doesn't work? Can you clarify what's being asked?

Comment: I know there shouldn't be any difference.. but for some reason doing the text() will fail the validation with special characters. That's why I need no emulate what express.raw() does because there is probably some encoding handling on the top of the process

Comment: Are you saying this line of code `event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body.text(), sig, endpointSecret);` throws an error? What kind of error? Why are special characters being passed to a function that doesn't allow them? There are many questions about what's being asked because there's not enough information or troubleshooting to understand what the issue is. Also, how is body parsing going to help with special characters? You can't just parse them out - they have a purpose, right? Can you clarify the question?